# DataFrame optional "condition" to filter nothing

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that modifies a DataFrame, plots things, then returns the updated DataFrame.  I want to optionally pass a condition to the function that will be applied to filter the data before plotting.

For example:
`df[condition].plot()`

This will happily plot the contents of `df`, filtering based on the criteria I provide in `condition`.  But what if *sometimes* I don't want to filter anything.  Is there something simple I can pass in `condidtion`, so that it essentially behaves like `df[:].plot()`?

Here's an executable example:

````
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df.plot()

condition = df.b != 5
df[condition]           # works fine, filtering out the second row

condition = None
df[condition]           # would like to filter nothing, but raises KeyError```
````

Comment: But it seems that ```df[True]``` creates a key error @sshashank124

Comment: Oh my bad, mentally registered numpy instead of pandas. Sorry

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @rpanai added mcve

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new dataframe that contains all `True` values that matches the shape of the original dataframe `df` you are attempting to filter and pass that as your mask:

```
condition = pd.DataFrame(True, index=np.arange(df.shape[0]), columns=df.columns)

df[condition]
```

Comment: thanks, that would work, though I'm still curious if a condition can be defined that essentially says "filter nothing", without testing or constructing a new DataFrame.  Similar to your solution, i've thought about simply passing ```df[df.index.notna()]```.  That is, set ```condition = df.index.notna()```.

Comment: @CrashLandon You can have your function defined with `condition=None` by default then you have two options. The first is to have two separate blocks with `if condition is None: df.plot() else df[condition].plot()`. That tends to be too duplicative and is prone to errors of changing one block and not the other, so I often find it better to do what this solution suggests, `if condition is None: condition = pd.DataFrame(...)` that way later you can keep the more complicated block to a single method `df[condition].plot()`, regardless of whether it was `None` to begin with.